# iPhone 8 randomly locks the screen while I'm using it

Tags: iphone

Sometimes when I'm actively using the phone the lock screen pops up and I have to unlock.

145 others have upvoted this problem at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8127644 . I tried the only suggestion, which was to set the time to the past just before upgrading iOS, but the problem persists. I'm on 11.3 now.

Help?

Any logs I can look at to get a clue?

Comment: Can I get it swapped even though the screen is cracked?

Comment: The screen might not be the issue. I'm thinking software or proximity sensor.

Comment: Out of warranty Apple Store will make you pay for the screen replacement before they will repair it.

Answer (score 4):

How often does this occur throughout the day or week?

Try to backup your iPhone and then restore it with iTunes. Once you get a chance to setup the iPhone then restore from the backup and then test the phone again. Usually this is a software glitch.

If it occurs afterwards do the restore again and don't restore your backup this time. Use the phone without the backup to test the issue. If its still present then it is a hardware sensor issue.

Comment: It happens about 5 times per day. I haven't backed up the iPhone before -- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977 says I can use either iCloud or iTunes. Do you recommend iTunes over iCloud?

If it does appear to be a hardware sensor issue, what would be the recommended course of action?

Comment: I recommend both (in case one doesn't work well) but for most cases, iCloud is much more convenient since you can backup and restore the backup via the phone itself, a wifi connection (you'll need the password) and your Apple ID email and password sign in. If it appears to be a hardware issue, then I recommend setting up an appointment for your local Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider.

Comment: Any luck @dgrogan

Comment: About to go on a long trip, won't have time to factory reset before then. But your plan to isolate whether it's hardware or software is good; thanks for all the info.

Comment: Finally swapped out the hardware at an apple store but the problem still happens. The remaining hypotheses are (1) a misbehaving app or (2) corrupted iOS settings stored in iCloud. Going to start with 1 by uninstalling groups of apps each day until the problem stops, then narrowing down from there. If that doesn't seem to work then will try 2 by factory wiping then not restoring from iCloud and instead installing apps and changing settings manually :(

Comment: I agree with this synopsis. The 2nd hypothesis will usually work 90% of the time.